# Normalise testing data using scale_ and mean_ from standardscaler of sklearn from outside of original code

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, normalization

I have a training data set used to determine coefficients of equation in a multivariate regression.
Before doing this I have normalised data set using

> scale = StandardScaler()
>
> normalisedData = scale.fit_tranform(data)

Then I used ordinary least square from statsmodels.api to determine coefficients.

At a different place I am getting new data as input and have to find the final value. The stored coefficients can be used for this.

But before plugging input into equation, it has to be transformed. Now I can store mean_ and scale_ also from training data, but I am not sure of how to use these to normalise data now on input.

I know normailisation is done using the formula

> x′=(x−μ)/σ

Can the values from mean_(μ) and scale_(σ) functions be directly used as per this formula.

Input data has 10 variables. So mean_ and scale_ are arrays of sizes 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not save the standardScaler using joblib and load it at the new location and call the `scale.transform()` on the new data.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for the suggestion. Did this and it worked.